# Taptic Engine and Alerts

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to get an alert going. I want my phone to vibrate really hard.

```
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator *generator = [[UIImpactFeedbackGenerator alloc] initWithStyle:UIImpactFeedbackStyleHeavy];

[generator impactOccurred];
```

Here's my Objective-C

Does nothing though.

Ideas?

Eventually I'd like to set off a series of 8 taptic shakes.

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 10** introduced new ways of generating haptic feedback using predefined vibration patterns shared by all apps, thus helping users understand that various types of feedback carry special significance.

> At this time, only the new Taptic Engine found in the **iPhone 7** and **iPhone 7 Plus** or newer support these APIs. Other devices silently ignore the haptic requests.

for more details: [How to generate haptic feedback with UIFeedbackGenerator](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator)